# Jar contains com.google.gson.Gson; yet doesn't?

Tags: java, jar, compiler-errors, package, gson

So I'm trying to compile some code, and get an error telling me com.google.gson doesn't exists:

```
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2494 source files to /home/zack/dev/nanoseis/classes
    [javac] /home/zack/dev/nanoseis/src/com/azure-event-hubs-java-dev/azure-eventhubs-eph/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/eventprocessorhost/AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager.java:8: error: package com.google.gson does not exist
    [javac] import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

Okay not problem, I'll download the jar that contains it from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/).

I extract the .jar to confirm that it has com/google/gson/Gson.class in it, it does.

I place it in my lib directory, and cofirm that the system can see it:

> [zack@minnow02 com]$ pw.sh which gson-2.6.2.jar

```
/home/zack/dev/nanoseis/lib/gson-2.6.2.jar
```

Yet I still get the same compilation error. I don't understand.

Comment: Doesn't matter if the system can see it if it's not on your Java classpath.

Comment: This is one of the reasons tools like maven, sbt, gradle and ivy are popular (they can resolve build dependencies)...

Comment: How did you build your jar (that you are trying to run)?